# SignalR How to receive a custom data type?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, signalr

I am working on a server using SignalR and Asp.Net Core 2.2.

I have a function on the server side that can receive 3 parameters, 2 of these parameters are optional. This is not supported in SignalR. But to counter that I created a class to act as a custom datatype.

https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/8853

But when i invoke the function via the client I get this error:

```
Failed to invoke hub method 'CreateRoom'.
System.IO.InvalidDataException: Error binding arguments. Make sure that the types of the provided values match the types of the hub method being invoked. ---> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: Error converting value 2 to type 'GameServer.Classes.CreateParams'. Path '[0]', line 1, position 15. ---> System.ArgumentException: Could not cast or convert from System.Int64 to GameServer.Classes.CreateParams.
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Utilities.ConvertUtils.EnsureTypeAssignable(Object value, Type initialType, Type targetType) in /_/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Utilities/ConvertUtils.cs:line 616
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Utilities.ConvertUtils.ConvertOrCast(Object initialValue, CultureInfo culture, Type targetType) in /_/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Utilities/ConvertUtils.cs:line 587
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.EnsureType(JsonReader reader, Object value, CultureInfo culture, JsonContract contract, Type targetType) in /_/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Serialization/JsonSerializerInternalReader.cs:line 982
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.EnsureType(JsonReader reader, Object value, CultureInfo culture, JsonContract contract, Type targetType) in /_/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Serialization/JsonSerializerInternalReader.cs:line 989
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.Deserialize(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, Boolean checkAdditionalContent) in /_/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Serialization/JsonSerializerInternalReader.cs:line 167
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.DeserializeInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType) in /_/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/JsonSerializer.cs:line 907
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken.ToObject(Type objectType, JsonSerializer jsonSerializer) in /_/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Linq/JToken.cs:line 2070
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Protocol.JsonHubProtocol.BindArguments(JArray args, IReadOnlyList`1 paramTypes)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Protocol.JsonHubProtocol.BindArguments(JArray args, IReadOnlyList`1 paramTypes)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Protocol.JsonHubProtocol.ParseMessage(Utf8BufferTextReader textReader, IInvocationBinder binder)
```

Here is my code.

Beginning of the server side function.

**GameHub.cs**

```
public async Task CreateRoom(CreateParams data)
        {
            Log.Information("CreateRoom is called with Game: {0}, RoomName: {1}", data.Game, data.RoomName);

            try
            {
                int _MaxUsers = 2;
                if (data.MaxUsers != null)
                {
                    if (data.MaxUsers <= 2)
                    {
                        _MaxUsers = 2;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        _MaxUsers = (int)data.MaxUsers;
                    }
                }
```

Custom class

**CreateParams**

```
public class CreateParams
    {
        public string Game { get; set; }
        public string RoomName { get; set; }
        public int? MaxUsers { get; set; }
    }
```

**Client**

```
connection.invoke("CreateRoom", (gameType, lobbyName, maxUsers));
```

I don't know why this is happening.
I hope you guys can help me.

**EDIT**

I tried what you gave me but i get this error:

```
Source: System.Collections.Concurrent, Method: ThrowKeyNullException, Error: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: key, Stack Trace:    at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.ThrowKeyNullException()
   at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.TryGetValue(TKey key, TValue& value)
   at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.get_Item(TKey key)
   at GameServer.Hubs.GameHub.CreateRoom(CreateParams data) in projectlocation\GameServer\GameServer\Hubs\GameHub.cs:line 149
2019-04-15 14:34:50.504 +02:00 [ERR] Failed to invoke hub method 'CreateRoom'.
System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: key
   at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.ThrowKeyNullException()
   at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.TryGetValue(TKey key, TValue& value)
   at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.get_Item(TKey key)
   at GameServer.Hubs.GameHub.CreateRoom(CreateParams data) in projectlocation\GameHub.cs:line 149
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Internal.DefaultHubDispatcher`1.ExecuteHubMethod(ObjectMethodExecutor methodExecutor, THub hub, Object[] arguments)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Internal.DefaultHubDispatcher`1.Invoke(HubMethodDescriptor descriptor, HubConnectionContext connection, HubMethodInvocationMessage hubMethodInvocationMessage, Boolean isStreamedInvocation)
```

I logged the response and all parameters are null

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your client is sending the wrong parameters. You send gameType, lobbyName and maxUsers but the class needs Game, RoomName, MaxUsers

```
const params={
  Game: gameType,
  RoomName: lobbyName,
  MaxUsers: maxUsers
}
connection.invoke("CreateRoom", params);
```

should solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Create a json object on client side as below:

```
const param={
 gameType:gameType,
 lobbyName: lobbyName,
 maxUsers: maxUsers
}
```

And, pass this object to invoke method like so:

```
connection.invoke("CreateRoom", param);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Look at my Edit